# Simultanous scrolling of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Inside my app I have to implement a scenario where i need to make two scroll view follow each other scroll.I searched in stackoverflow ,and i see many answers for that.But here in my case those answers are not applicable because my scrollview is being created in a different way.That means,I have a class named MyScrollView inside which I have a single line of code for creating ScrollView.I am not creating two scrollview like scrollViewA and scrollViewB,Instead have another view inside which i will make call for craeting scrollviews using different object.In tht case how will i compare the scrollviews.

Comment: ok..you are asking for scrollview have scrollview as it's subview. look these links  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437515/uiscrollview-inside-uiscrollview     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910378/how-can-i-nest-a-uiscrollview-inside-a-uiscrollview-so-that-the-user-can-scroll     http://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/scrollviews-inside-scrollviews/

Comment: no it is not scrollview inside scrollview.I have two seperate scrollview created using same uiview class by using two different objects

Answer (score 0):

Put tag values to your scroll views. so that you can handle at the time of delegate methods.